# What option provide to CMake to demangle stackframe output?

Tags: gcc, cmake, elf

To print the stackframe [this method](https://gist.github.com/fmela/591333) is used. But it prints mostly executable name with addresses.

```
0   ./fish(+0xa307b) [0x556c9198c07b]
1   ./fish(+0xb0cf2) [0x556c91999cf2]
2   ./fish(+0xb218a) [0x556c9199b18a]
3   ./fish(+0x151c2) [0x556c918fe1c2]
4   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x29d90) [0x7fb0f2973d90]
5   __libc_start_main + 128
6   ./fish(+0x16ff5) [0x556c918ffff5]
```

The project itself uses `CMake`, generating with `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug` doesn't help.
What option do I need to provide to CMake to get more clear output?

Answer (score 0):

Program needs to have all symbols. `GCC` option to say linker about it is:

> -rdynamic
> Pass the flag -export-dynamic to the ELF linker, on targets that support it. This instructs the linker to add all symbols, not only used ones, to
> the dynamic symbol table. This option is needed for some uses of "dlopen" **or to allow obtaining backtraces from within a program**

The problem was solved using [CMAKE_ENABLE_EXPORTS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_ENABLE_EXPORTS.html#variable:CMAKE_ENABLE_EXPORTS) variable. Executing `cmake -DCMAKE_ENABLE_EXPORTS=ON ..` or providing `set(CMAKE_ENABLE_EXPORTS ON)` in CMakeLists.txt deals with the problem.

```
0   reader_data_t::is_repaint_needed(std::vector<highlight_spec_t, std::allocator<highlight_spec_t> > const*) const + 59
1   reader_data_t::readline[abi:cxx11](int) + 498
2   reader_read(parser_t&, int, io_chain_t const&) + 730
3   main + 6706
4   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x29d90) [0x7f6f22628d90]
5   __libc_start_main + 128
6   _start + 37
```